# How to embed urls as https in angularjs depending on the browser url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If any launches my webpage build with `angularjs` using `https`, any urls used within the webpage should also be opened using `https`, instead of the default `http`.

Is that possible to force angularjs using either http or https depending on the initial request?

The embedded links are for example:
`<img href="my.dns.com/rest" />` without http or https in front. By default angulajrjs uses always http here.

Comment: `href="//my.dns.com/rest"`. And, actually, it has no relation to angular

Comment: OK I see, thanks that works. Would you mind adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [protocol relative url](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). Like `href="//my.dns.com/rest"` so the scheme (http or https) will depend on source, from which web page loaded